# Torque 3d versus Ogre 3d?

Tags: c++, ogre3d, torque3d

Well Id just like to to ask everyones opinion on which people would recommand:
Ogre 3d which is free  found here http://www.ogre3d.org
         or
Torque 3d which costs 179 dollars  found here http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-3d

I will be going into my fourth and final year in college soon and I just want to start preparing for it now.
I am doing games development and money isnt an option. 
Id just like to get peoples honest opinions

Comment: Please have a look at the faq for reasons why this isn't an appropriate question here.

Comment: Well, let's see. Ogre3D is a scene graph, a rendering system. Torque3D is a *game engine*. It therefore includes more stuff that you might need for a game: collision detection, entities, sound, etc. Ogre3D is just a renderer.

Comment: Torque 3D is now also free

Comment: I remember that several years ago when Irrlicht was getting popular, I used Ogre with YAKE (site is temporarily down, so check the summary for example here http://www.3dxo.com/software/4824_yake, not to be mistaken with JAKE) and it was quite clean and usable.. But, I had to kill the projects and I don't know how does it do today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know only Ogre3D a little bit. I don't know the other one. But my argument is in another direction: I don't think that you need the "extras" that you perhaps can gain from a licensed product. I would use the money for something else. Ogre3D is complex and powerful enough to have you going for a couple of years. And if you really come to an end with it there are either [other](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) [free](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) [alternatives](http://www.crystalspace3d.org/main/Main_Page) or you can still come back yo Torqu3d.